# Force generic method argument to be the full union passed in

Tags: typescript

Trying to force a method with a generic parameter to have a union type. The issue is that TS is fine with the implementation of this method to only satisfy the union, rather than actually *be* the union. I might be misusing the satisfy terminology here, but I hope my point comes across clearly in the example below.

```js
interface IFoo<TArg> {
  myMethod(arg: TArg): void;
}

class Foo implements IFoo<string | number> {
  // TS doesn't complain because string satisfies string | number.
  // How can I make TypeScript force arg to explicitly be string | number?
  myMethod(arg: string): void {
    //
  }
}


class Foo2 implements IFoo<string | number> {
  // What I want TS to enforce:
  myMethod(arg: string | number): void {
    //
  }
}
```

I messed around with tuples and tried looking for a helper type that could solve this to no avail.

edit: Link to playground: https://tsplay.dev/wOx5EN

Comment: Huh, yeah this seems not ideal: https://tsplay.dev/mp8xXm. Or more simply: https://tsplay.dev/m33v2m

Comment: Although when using the type directly (as opposed to `implements`) leaving the argument type off does the right thing. https://tsplay.dev/wXzrDm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running up against the fact that [method parameters are *bivariant*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) in TypeScript.  That means you are allowed to narrow the type of a method parameter when implementing an interface, like narrowing `string | number` to just `string`.  That's not type safe (what if someone calls `myMethod()` with a number argument?), but it is convenient for some important use cases (you could also see [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) for why).

Now, this used to be the case for *all* functions, but since [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) was introduced, you can restrict the bivariance check to just *methods*, while other function types would have their parameters checked in the safe *contravariant* way.  (You can look at [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for more information.)

That means one way you can sidestep the issue is to declare `myMethod()` in `IFoo<TArg>` as a property with a [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) instead of a method type:

```
interface IFoo<TArg> {
  myMethod: (arg: TArg) => void;
}
```

It might look like that would force implementing classes to make `myMethod` an instance property instead of a method, but that's not the case.  So this works just fine:

```
class Foo2 implements IFoo<string | number> {
  myMethod(arg: string | number): void { // okay
    //
  }
}
```

But even if you implement it as a method, the parameter is now checked contravariantly against the interface function property parameter:

```
class Foo implements IFoo<string | number> {
  myMethod(arg: string): void { // error!!!
    //
  }
}
```

and you get the error you were looking for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2mA8AVAQSgHMA+ZAbwFgAoZZAWwE8BZCMAC0wBMAuZABRwS-QiQCUyALzkAbpmDcA3LQC+tDTQQAbOAGc9yLJgBMyYAwAO2iAwjhDGbDj1gooYsgA+yEAFcGACNocmo6RlZ2Lm4hEWRXdxBPH38g6HF+eUVKWnp6AHp83OR1GlKdfUNjcysbOwc0Yxc3D29fAOCoUOLmNk4eWOJ+BI8M5CzuSmRC5GgoTCgAQmKCovDS0togA)